# Why can't IntelliJ work with single files?

Tags: file, intellij-idea, ide

I get that as an IDE IntelliJ focuses on projects. But is it possible to open/create single files without starting a new project all over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it not possible. IDEA it's not easy text editor like Sublime Text or Notepad++. But you can create project with simple structure and open(drag and drop) or create there any files.