# Use IDEA 13 as a notepad

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, editor

Is it possible to use IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 (Ultimate) as a notepad?

I would like it to be the default editor for, say, .java files.

So I could open and edit files in it, but not create a project for each time I need to open a file.

Just work like sublime text for example.

Comment: **[Why can't IntelliJ work with single files?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23040526/2650174)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. IDEA can only open a file if there is a project defined. The reason is simple... It can't know how to provide editing support -- i.e. code completion, syntax & error highlighting, etc. -- for the Java files without a JDK defined. (Keep in mind, IDEA is an IDE, not an editor.) And of course, if the file uses libraries... well those need to be configured.

I personally have a scratch-pad/whiteboard project configured. I then use that to view/edit an one off files, or to write a little method to try something out. I simply always have it open in addition to the active project I'm working on.

Another option is to use the Scratch File feature. This isn't for opening an existing file, but can be use to have a temporary scratch pad file (of any file type IDEA supports). It needs to be enabled in order to use it. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73814#comment=27-695054 for information.

Comment: Needless to say that IDEA 14 supports that.

Comment: Yes, opening a single file without a project.

Comment: @Meo, wow, that sounds awesome. Got any link with this feature described?

Comment: @user3733425 I can't find anything.

Comment: @Meo, so how do u know it's there? ;D